# Centering the Stripe PaymentKit credit card textfield in the view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, stripe-payments

I am using code from Stripe PaymentKit.  They've provided the code for the PaymentViewController and I want the textfield to be centered in the view but I can't figure out how.  I can change the position and width/height easily but I want it to be horizontally centered... Any ideas?

Comment: I've added a plus 1, because the SO jerks have been here, I see...  just to down vote questions they don't think are worthy of their supreme brainpower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround by modifying the x coordinate:

```
float X_Co = (self.view.frame.size.width - 290)/2;
self.paymentView = [[PTKView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(X_Co, 240, 290, 55)];
```

Answer (score 3):

I placed an empty UIView inside my presenting view controller in Storyboard, set its width to be 290 and the height to be 55 (the width and height of the PTKView), set it to align center X with the Superview, and created a referencing outlet in my view controller named `paymentViewArea`.

Then I loaded the PTKView into that view

```
self.paymentView = PTKView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 290, 55))
self.paymentViewArea.addSubview(self.paymentView)
```